As a newbie, how do I install numpy as a module please?
I have returned to python after a long break.
I have the following error in my code to understand and resolve: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'.
I am using a Mac and working in VSstudio - how do I install numpy as a module please?
I have tried searching extensions for the numpy module, and working through messages on this platform.

To resolve the issue:

Open Terminal on your Mac.

Install NumPy by running the following command:
pip3 install numpy


Verify the installation with this command:
python3 -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)"


In VS Code, open the Command Palette by pressing Cmd + Shift + P. Search for Python: Select Interpreter and select the Python environment where NumPy is installed.



Thank you Irfan (and other respondents), these steps were clear and worked well.  Scott

...and steps 1 & 2 worked for  pandas  and matplotlib modules also thank you

Install it using
pip install numpy

and import it in you code like this
import numpy as np

then you can use it like
np.array()


According to this https://numpy.org/install/
Just do:
pip install numpy

